MCTS/Alpha Style Algorithms and reward propagation
I'm just going through the literature at the moment and i'm stuck on this point.
Consider a 2 player zero-sum game using AlphaZero. We'll use Chess as the classic Example. During Self-Play, the algorithm takes both players role, and during search, nodes are explored according to several statistics stored within the node:

$N(s,a)$ - Number of times $(s,a)$ has been traversed during the given search
$Q(s,a)$ - Backed up action-value estimate of $(s,a)$
$P(s,a)$ - Prior probabilities of selecting action a from s.

During search, we expand nodes according PUCT, namely
$$\underset{a}{\arg\max}~Q(s,a)+c_{puct}P(s,a)\frac{\sqrt{N(s)}}{1+N(s,a)}$$
with $N(s)$ being the number of times state s has been visited during the given search and $c_{puct} > 0$ (Exploration constant).
At a terminal node (leaf) i believe we propagate through the parent nodes a reward value (-1,0,1) for white loss, draw and white win respectively.
But doesn't this make $Q > 0$ for white favourable paths, and $Q < 0$ for black favourable paths? - which by taking the argmax would favour white play over black?
if we're at node B - Black to play with two legal moves, one leads to white win, one to black win. we'll throw in 10 draws each too so that $N(s) = 40$ and $N(s,1) = 20 ~\&~N(s,2) =20$ and ($c_{puct} = 1)$ with both nodes as terminal (as they lead to mate sequences) - we'd be left with
$$(\text{Move 1}): \frac{10}{21}+P(s,1)\frac{2\sqrt{10}}{21}$$
$$(\text{Move 2}): -\frac{10}{21}+P(s,2)\frac{2\sqrt{10}}{21}$$
as the search result of this position, and the argmax would favour Move 1 (leading to white win) despite it being black to play.
Is the reward propagation meant to be alternating from the perspective of play? so +1 for white win on white nodes, -1 for white win on black nodes? and vice versa for black win? or are we meant to factor in play perspective as well?
if anyone could take the time to explain this quickly i'd be grateful.
